# eMule startup slow on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emule

I've been using eMule for years both on Windows 98 and XP and its interface has always been quite fast. However, since I upgraded to Windows 7 64bit, I noticed that eMule takes a long time to startup (2 to 3 minutes) and there is a noticeable freeze when I connect to an e2dk server (about 30 seconds).

I tested it in 2 different computer and it's always the same. Anyone has any idea about what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out what's going on. The slowness is proportional to the amount of files one is sharing.

The only solution so far is to reduce the number of shared files.